# Method Level security with permissions not roles

Tags: spring-security

- I want to make method level security for my spring application.
- The security design is as follows: **User > Roles > Permissions**
- Well when i use `@PreAuthorize` with `hasRole` it works fine.
- But when i try to use it with `hasPermission`, it doesn't work.
- I found that i should use **Spring ACL** for such approach, but it seems to be over-killing for the requirement.
- So is there's any way to define role permissions in xml file, or any other workarounds or other ways to get **method level security** works with **permissions** instead of roles, and withour using ACL.
- If there's no way but to use ACL, then please suggest me a good example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the article on the following site:
http://springinpractice.com/2010/10/27/quick-tip-spring-security-role-based-authorization-and-permissions/

The main thing is you will need to implement the UserDetails interface. It says
"the UserDetails interface simply exposes the permissions (not the roles) via the getAuthorities() method"

Comment: i know about this solution, i was thinking of a way to map between the role and it's permissions in the configuration but not via ACL.

Comment: anyway above solution works fine with me, by publishing permissions into user details instead of roles.